# Enviar email con Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, email

Literalmente esa es mi duda, como puedo enviar un correo electrónico usando las funciones que proporciona Firebase? Cualquier clase de informacion me sirve ya que no he usado mucho las funciones de Firebase, pretendo enviar un correo de bienvenida a un usuario que se acabe de registrar en mi web, el trigger onCreate funciona correctamente pero no tengo ni idea de como enviar el correo hacia el usuario cuyo correo esta almacenado en la real time database

Answer (score 0):

[Aquí](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/README.md) te dejo algo que te puede ayudar, incluye una [demo](https://fir-ui-demo-84a6c.firebaseapp.com) de un registro de usuarios que cuando se registra manda un email de confirmación o de bienvenida.

PD: esta en inglés. Suerte

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano :)